How to write a function to read csv files with different separators in pandas in Python?
I have a bunch of CSV files for different years named my_file_2019, my_file_2020, my_file_2023 and so on. Some files have tab separator while others have semi-colon.
I want to write a common function to extract data from all files.
This was my initial function:
def get_data(year):
    
    file = f"my_file_{year}.csv"
    
    df = pd.read_csv(file,
                    sep = "\t")
    
    #filter for germany
    df = df[df["CountryCode"] == "DE"]
    
    return df
    
    

I called the functions like below to get data from file for each year.
df_2019 = get_data(2019)
df_2020 = get_data(2020)
df_2021 = get_data(2021)
df_2022 = get_data(2022)
df_2023 = get_data(2023)

I got KeyError: 'CountryCode' when the separator was different.
I used the try except method as shown
def get_data(year):
    
    file = f"my_file_{year}.csv"
    
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(file,
                    sep = "\t")
    
    except KeyError:
        df = pd.read_csv(file,
                    sep = ";")
    
    #filter for germany
    df = df[df["CountryCode"] == "DE"]
    
    return df
    

Then I can still read the file when the separator is tab, but not semi-colon.
How can I fix this?

I was able to fix it by passing a list of possible separators.
By going through a for loop, I'd try each separator.
If i don't find the required column, it would break and try with another separator.
    def get_data(year):
        
        file = f"my_file_{year}.csv"
        
        separators = ["\t", ";",None]
        df = None
        
        for sep in separators:
            df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=sep,
                            engine = "python")
            
            if "CountryCode" in df.columns:
                break   
        df = df[df["CountryCode"] == "DE"]
        return df

